# Is it proper/safe to generate random anchor href and image src via JavaScript on the index of my website?

Tags: javascript, html

On my **index page**, I have a section that displays a different anchor href and image src depending on the date, via JavaScript switch, e.g.:

HTML

```
<a id="dailyDeal" href="index.html" title="Daily Deal"><img src="loading.gif" alt="Daily Deal" /></a>
```

JavaScript

```
switch (md) {
    case '0-1': // New Year
        document.getElementById('dailyDeal').href = 'deals/new-year.html';
        document.getElementById('dailyDeal').innerHTML = '<img src="images/deals/new-year.jpg" alt="Daily Deal" />';
        break;
        // ... and so on
```

I like to have certain (not too important) content that is dynamic, but I was curious to know the pros/cons, and possibly the effect it would have on SEO and/or validation in general.

Comment: What do you mean by _validation_?

Comment: Search engines will generally not see changes you make to your page via client-side Javascript because most do not execute your javascript and they certainly don't execute it every day to change your indexing every day.  So, it is likely that your page will get indexed with the HTML that comes from the server and the effect of this JS will not be included in the search engine in any way.

Comment: As it stands, throwing my html into the validator will show no error, but the validator doesn't actually read my JavaScript, which makes me wonder if what I'm doing has any drawbacks. E.g.: Warning: Using JS on an index page to generate different src/href is bad... etc.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00, that's what I needed to know, I just couldn't think of the proper question I suppose. Awesome. Care to add that as an answer?